# Connect phpmyadmin to existing db server

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I would like to access and modify records in an existing database server using phpmyadmin.

I am currently using the XAMPP testing server and can access the default localhost/phpmyadmin.

I tried to see if there is some config file I can point to the db server using the hostname, username, and password, i.e. `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` however, I have not succeeded with that.

I was wondering if someone ever accomplished this task with phpmyadmin?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to use your existing phpMyAdmin installation to connect to a different MySQL server?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to use my existing phpMyAdmin on my 'testing' xampp server to connect to a 'production' db mySQL server by changing the credentials (host, username, password, etc).

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can add another server to config.inc.php, as long as the other MySQL server allows remote connections. The [phpMyAdmin wiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/multiserver) has an example. Also, the included documentation has more in-depth information.

Basically you'll edit config.inc.php and add (or edit) the [host value](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_host) (and, if your auth_type is config, also the user and password values).

Here's a short example of how to do the multiserver, see the links I referenced for more details.

```
<?php 
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'setthistosomethingelse';
$i = 0;  

$i++; // server 1
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']   = 'Development server';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']      = 'localhost';

$i++; // server 2
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']   = 'Production server'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']      = 'production.example.com';

?>
```